# Serve an NFS mount over TFTP

Tags: freebsd, nfs, timeout, pxe-boot, tftp

I have a FreeBSD server on which I would like to run a TFTP server (for PXE). My daemon of choice is [`tftp-hpa`](http://freecode.com/projects/tftp-hpa) and I have it configured to serve from `/tftpboot` properly. It works *unless* I mount `/tftpboot` via NFS. Here is some more information...

- `sockstat -4l` confirms `in.tftpd` is running on *:69 (which is correct)
- `telnet` obviously doesn't work (UDP) but when I try to grab a file that exists, I get a timeout.
- There's no loot in `/var/log/messages`
- When I request a file that does not exist, I get the proper error

Any ideas?

Comment: I do the same thing at work, with tftpd-hpa, and it works fine.  Albeit on linux, not freebsd.

Comment: Try adding -v to the tftp server's launch arguments.  This may give you a bit more information to debug this.

Comment: @devicenull, that led me to believe it was a problem outside of the TFTP server. Verbose logging showed all requests properly (including retries) but gave no evidence of a response.

Answer (score 1):

If your NFS mount is exported read-only (regardless of whether it is mounted rw or ro), this seems to cause tftpd-hpa to exhibit this behavior. While I’ve no idea why, exporting rw resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not end up resolving this. I opted to serve TFTP from the file server (which exports `/tftpboot`). In addition to actually working, it's a lot faster. If anyone wants help debugging this issue in the future, feel free to contact me.